# ¿Cómo solucionar error "Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT)"?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.android

Estoy desarrollando una App en Xamarin.android que utiliza Firma Digital y últimamente la clase que utilizo para estampar dicha firma presenta muchos problemas.
Esta vez el problema que trae es:

> Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 30481 (al.FirmaDigital)

Pero como soy bastante nuevo en Xamarin no tengo idea por qué sucede.
Por lo que estuve investigando, este error aparece cuando un programa envía una señal para abortar el proceso. Pero no sé qué estaría causando esto.

Lo único que sé es que ese error aparece cuando se ejecuta la linea 175 del código: `objSignedCms.ComputeSignature(objCmsSigner, false);` (No está de más decir que el try/catch que le puse no devuelve ninguna excepción).

Dejo aquí la clase que utilizo para firmar a ver si alguien puede ayudarme.

Gracias de antemano!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;


using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using Org.BouncyCastle.X509;
using SysX509 = System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs;

namespace FirmaDigital.FirmaDigital
{
    public static class PDF
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Firma un documento
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="Source">Documento origen</param>
        /// <param name="Target">Documento destino</param>
        /// <param name="Certificate">Certificado a utilizar</param>
        /// <param name="Reason">Razón de la firma</param>
        /// <param name="Location">Ubicación</param>
        /// <param name="AddVisibleSign">Establece si hay que agregar la firma visible al documento</param>
        /// FormatPlace. Posibles valores para Lugar de la firma:
        /// A4TL: A4 normal, arriba a la izquierda
        /// A4TR: A4 normal, arriba a la derecha
        /// A4BL: A4 normal, abajo a la izquierda
        /// A4BR: A4 normal, abajo a la derecha
        /// A4aTL: A4 apaisado, arriba a la izquierda
        /// A4aTR: A4 apaisado, arriba a la derecha
        /// A4aBL: A4 apaisado, abajo a la izquierda
        /// A4aBR: A4 apaisado, abajo a la derecha

        public static void SignHashed(string Source, string Target, SysX509.X509Certificate2 Certificate, string Reason, string Location, bool AddVisibleSign, string FormatPlace, string TSA)
        {
            X509CertificateParser objCP = new X509CertificateParser();
            X509Certificate[] objChain = new X509Certificate[] { objCP.ReadCertificate(Certificate.RawData) };

            PdfReader objReader = new PdfReader(Source);
            PdfStamper objStamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(objReader, new FileStream(Target, FileMode.Create), '\0');
            PdfSignatureAppearance objSA = objStamper.SignatureAppearance;

            int LastPage = objReader.NumberOfPages;

            if (AddVisibleSign)
            {
                switch (FormatPlace)
                {
                    case "A4TL":
                        objSA.SetVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(50, 750, 300, 780), LastPage, null);
                        break;
                    case "A4TR":
                        objSA.SetVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(350, 750, 600, 780), LastPage, null);
                        break;
                    case "A4BL":
                        objSA.SetVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(50, 50, 300, 80), LastPage, null);
                        break;
                    case "A4BR":
                        objSA.SetVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(350, 50, 600, 80), LastPage, null);
                        break;
                    case "A4aTL":
                        objSA.SetVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(50, 570, 300, 600), LastPage, null);
                        break;
                    case "A4aTR":
                        objSA.SetVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(530, 570, 780, 600), LastPage, null);
                        break;
                    case "A4aBL":
                        objSA.SetVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(50, 20, 300, 50), LastPage, null);
                        break;
                    case "A4aBR":
                        objSA.SetVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(530, 20, 780, 50), LastPage, null);
                        break;
                }
            }

            objSA.SignDate = DateTime.Now;
            objSA.Certificate = objChain[0];
            objSA.Reason = Reason;
            objSA.Location = Location;
            objSA.Acro6Layers = true;
            objSA.SignatureRenderingMode = PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.DESCRIPTION;
            PdfSignature objSignature = new PdfSignature(PdfName.ADOBE_PPKMS, PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_SHA1);
            objSignature.Date = new PdfDate(objSA.SignDate);
            objSignature.Name = "Nombre de Prueba";
            if (objSA.Reason != null)
                objSignature.Reason = objSA.Reason;
            if (objSA.Location != null)
                objSignature.Location = objSA.Location;
            objSA.CryptoDictionary = objSignature;
            int intCSize = 4000;
            Hashtable objTable = new Hashtable();
            objTable[PdfName.CONTENTS] = intCSize * 2 + 2;

            var dict = HashtableToDictionary<PdfName, int>(objTable);

            objSA.PreClose(dict);

            HashAlgorithm objSHA1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();

            Stream objStream = objSA.GetRangeStream();
            int intRead = 0;
            byte[] bytBuffer = new byte[8192];
            while ((intRead = objStream.Read(bytBuffer, 0, 8192)) > 0)
                objSHA1.TransformBlock(bytBuffer, 0, intRead, bytBuffer, 0);
            objSHA1.TransformFinalBlock(bytBuffer, 0, 0);

            byte[] bytPK = SignMsg(objSHA1.Hash, Certificate, false, Source, TSA);
            byte[] bytOut = new byte[intCSize];

            PdfDictionary objDict = new PdfDictionary();

            Array.Copy(bytPK, 0, bytOut, 0, bytPK.Length);

            objDict.Put(PdfName.CONTENTS, new PdfString(bytOut).SetHexWriting(true));
            objSA.Close(objDict);
        }

        public static Dictionary<K, V> HashtableToDictionary<K, V>(Hashtable table)
        {
            return table
              .Cast<DictionaryEntry>()
              .ToDictionary(kvp => (K)kvp.Key, kvp => (V)kvp.Value);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Crea la firma CMS/PKCS #7
        /// </summary>
        private static byte[] SignMsg(byte[] Message, SysX509.X509Certificate2 SignerCertificate, bool Detached, string Source, string TSA)
        {
            try
            {
                //Creamos el contenedor
                ContentInfo contentInfo = new ContentInfo(Message);

                //Instanciamos el objeto SignedCms con el contenedor
                SignedCms objSignedCms = new SignedCms(contentInfo, Detached);

                //Creamos el "firmante"
                CmsSigner objCmsSigner = new CmsSigner(SignerCertificate);

                // Include the following line if the top certificate in the
                // smartcard is not in the trusted list.
                objCmsSigner.IncludeOption = SysX509.X509IncludeOption.EndCertOnly;
                if (TSA != "S/TSA")
                {
                    objCmsSigner.UnsignedAttributes.Add(timeData);
                }

                //  Sign the CMS/PKCS #7 message. The second argument is needed to ask for the pin.
                objSignedCms.ComputeSignature(objCmsSigner, false);

                //Encodeamos el mensaje CMS/PKCS #7
                return objSignedCms.Encode();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Por favor use `catch (Exception ex) { string msg_error = ex.ToString(); }` para obtener la excepción completa.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave, fijate que había puesto en la publicación que el catch no me devuelve nada... solo se cierra la app diciendo "La aplicación se detuvo" y no muestra ningún mensaje de error, sólo el `Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT)`

Comment: el único catch que veo en su código es este: `catch (Exception) { throw; }` pero este catch no le mostrará el detalle de la descripción. Si no ha buscado aún, busque el error en Google. Los primeros resultados que obtuve indicaron que el error era porque faltaba alguna librería.

Comment: El problema es que no pasa por el catch. Igualmente lo cambié por `catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }` pero se cierra la App sin pasar por el catch. Hace 3 días que estoy con este error, ya he buscado en google (de hecho sigo buscando) y no encuentro una explicación concreta de cuándo puede suceder esto. Lo mejor explicado que encontré fue que aparece cuando un programa envía una señal para abortar el proceso, pero no sé qué estaría causando esto.